# Any way I can define and declare an extern object in header?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a library which is totally base on templates, so I don't have any cpp files. Now I want to declare an global variable, then I realize I have nowhere to go.

If I simply declared it in header, I will got a "multiple definition" error, if I use `extern`, I have to create a cpp file to really declare it.

So is there any way I can declare a global variable in header?

P.S. since a static member in a template class can (only) be declared in header, how it works?

Comment: add `inline` to the definition

Comment: @M.M, what if I'm using C++ 11? Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M.M mentioned, you can use `inline` declaration if you're on `C++17` or above.

Hovever, if that's not the case, you can declare `inline` function which returns a reference to `static` variable, just like that:

```c
inline int& getData() {
    static int data;
    return data;
}
```

Then, in your .cpp file (as well as in any function body inside your headers) you can simply call it like `int& data = getData()`.

As a side note, if you want to ensure that global object is created only once and is not copied by accident, it could suit you better to use a [signleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/5512095) instead. Global variables are more of a c-style and not really considered a good practice in c++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use macro to for single declaration,

```
#ifndef __usermacro
#define __usermacro
//Declare global variable
#else
//Declare extern 
#endif
```

Comment: `#ifnedf` do  not share between translation units, this does not work

Comment: Yes, that's true.  In single translation unit you can avoid multiple instances of the global variable